# Get sub-item's XPath using Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, subitem

I'm having problem trying to click a sub-item from a menu, in third step..

1. I do login
2. Enter into a project
3. Delete only card created
   I think problem its about to get the correct xpath
   PAGE

   package PageObject;
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
   public class Page {
       protected final WebDriver webDriver;

   ```
   public Page( final WebDriver driver ) {
       this.webDriver =driver;
   }

   protected WebElement element(By by ) {
       return webDriver.findElement( by );
   }

   public void pressEnter(){
       Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
       builder.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
   }
   ```

   }

PAGE OBJECT: CARD PAGE

```
package Helpers;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
public class public class CardPage extends PageObject.Page{

    By close = By.xpath("//*[@id='ngdialog5']/div[2]/div/div[2]");
    By menuCard = By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/ui-view/project/div[1]/board/div/div/div/backlog-list/div[2]/div/ul/li/ul/div[1]/card/li/div/div[1]/a[3]");
    By container1stCard = By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/ui-view/project/div[1]/board/div/div/div/backlog-list/div[2]/div/ul/li/ul/div/card/li/div");
    By delete3 = By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'delete')]");

    By accceptWarning = By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div[10]/button[1]");
    By openCard = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"scrollable\"]/div/backlog-list/div[2]/div/ul/li/ul/div/card/li/div");

    private Services services;
    public CardPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
    //SERVICES CARDS
    private void closeCard() {
        element(close).click();
    }
    public void delete1stCard(){
        WebElement Wcontainer1stCard = element(container1stCard);//Menu
        Actions builder = new Actions(super.webDriver);
        Actions hoverOverContainer = builder.moveToElement(Wcontainer1stCard);
        hoverOverContainer.perform();
        Services.waitMilisegundos(1000);
        element(menuCard).click();

        Services.waitMilisegundos(500);
        WebElement deleteBtn = element(delete3);
        deleteBtn.click();//Menu Item
        Services.waitMilisegundos(1000);
    }
    public void openCard(){
        element(openCard).click();
    }
}
```

SERVICES TO PAGE OBJECTS

```
package Helpers;

import PageObject.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class Services {
    WebDriver webDriver;
    private LandingPage landingPage;
    private MainPage mainPage;
    private LoginPage loginPage;
    private ProjectPage projectPage;
    private CardPage cardPage;
    String url;
    ////
    public Services(TmpEnvironment environment) {
        webDriver = new StartDriver( environment.url ).getWebDriver();
    }
    public Services() {
        webDriver = new StartDriver(TmpEnvironment.STAGING).getWebDriver();
    }

    ///LOGIN SERVICES
    public Services login(String email, String passw){
        getLandingPage().goToLoginPage();
        getLoginPage().writeUserName(email)
                .writePassword(passw)
                .clickOnLogin();
        return this;
    }
    public Services enterToProject() {
        getMainPage().enterToProject();
        return this;
    }
    //PAGES GETTERS
    public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
        return webDriver;
    }
    public MainPage getMainPage() {
        if (mainPage == null)
            mainPage = new MainPage(webDriver);
        return mainPage;
    }
    public LoginPage getLoginPage() {
        if (loginPage == null)
            loginPage = new LoginPage(webDriver);
        return loginPage;
    }
    public ProjectPage getProjectPage(){
        if (projectPage == null)
            projectPage = new  ProjectPage(webDriver);
        return projectPage;
    }
    public LandingPage getLandingPage() {
        if (landingPage == null)
            landingPage =  new LandingPage(webDriver);
        return landingPage;
    }
    public CardPage getCardPage() {
        if (cardPage == null)
            cardPage = new CardPage(webDriver);
        return cardPage;
    }
    //CARDS SERVICES
    public Services delete1stCard() {
        getCardPage().delete1stCard();
        return this;
    }
    public static void waitMilisegundos(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void pressEnter(){
        Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
        builder.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
    }
    public void pressEsc(){
        Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
        builder.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform();
    }
    //
    public Services goToLoginPage() {
        getLandingPage().goToLoginPage();
        return this;
    }

    public enum TmpEnvironment {
        DEVELOPMENT( "http://tmp-landing-dev.theamalgama.com/index" ),
        STAGING( "https://tmpapp.theamalgama.com" ),
        PRODUCTION( "https://tmpapp.com" );
        public final String url;
        TmpEnvironment( final String url ) {
            this.url = url;
        }
        public String getUrl(){
            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

TEST CLASS

```
package z_Test;

import Helpers.Services;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import static Helpers.Services.waitMilisegundos;

public class CardTest {
    static String email, password;
    Services services;

    public CardTest(){
        services = new Services();
    }
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setData(){
        email = "test01@testing.com";
        password = "password";

    }
    @After
    public void CloseDriver(){
        services.getWebDriver().close();
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Test
    public void cardTest(){ 
        services.login(email,password);
        services.enterToProject()
        .delete1stCard();
        waitMilisegundos();
    }
}
```

and next its the error message when try to delete card.

> [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
>   (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.30.477691
>   (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux
>   4.4.0-79-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 96 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'julieta', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-79-generic', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_131' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.30.477691
>   (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),
>   userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.rQuYOu},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   version=58.0.3029.110, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}] Session ID:
>   a33c710a9bae046f731a66bb56b344b8  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:82)
>     at PageObject.CardPage.delete1stCard(CardPage.java:92)  at
>   Helpers.Services.delete1stCard(Services.java:201)     at
>   z_Test.CardTest.cardTest(CardTest.java:69)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>
> ]

Also I tried using a diferent xpath, so wen i run it i get another kind of exeption: `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:`

Comment: What is your code? what you do mean by why am I failing? You never mentioned what you have done and how exactly it is failing

Comment: yes, im sorry! i'll edit my post right now

Comment: You are performing action of movetoelement but not doing click with the same action itself? You should chain these together, menuCard and deleteBtn click

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks. First of all I open the menu doing click  element(menuCard).click();
And then i choose one from the option in the menu:
 element(delete3).click();//Menu Item
This order works fine because Ive already use it in other interaction with menus and works good. I think the problem is the xpath. I post it 'Element' method to make clearer my code. 
`protected WebElement element(By by ) {
        return webDriver.findElement( by );
    }`

Comment: Please write (in English) what your test steps are intended to be. I'm having a hard time following your intent after logging in. Your code is referencing a number of variables that are not located in the code you provided. Please update your code with an [mcve].

Comment: ok @JeffC, ive edited my post, i hope its clearer -

Comment: Nope. Now please actually read [mcve] and provide one. You've dumped all your code. No one wants to look at all that. It's too much for something as simple as finding an element on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got a number of issues that need to be improved.

1. You are using absolute XPaths which is always a bad practice. They are extremely fragile. You should spend some time reading some tutorials on handcrafting XPaths. They will be shorter, easier to read, but also much less fragile.
2. Rather than having a method `delete1stCard()`, create a method `deleteCard(int index)` that takes an index so that you can delete whichever card you want. You would probably want another method `deleteCard(String cardName)` that takes in a card name and deletes it. I think that would probably be more useful than deleting by index but I don't know what your test cases look like. (or better yet, implement a card component class, as I suggest below, and it solves this problem.)
3. Your class called `Services` seems to be a catch all bucket. Do a proper page object model and add a Login page that handles logins from the login page, a Projects page that handles that page, and so forth. I don't know what `Services` should hold once you've reorganized everything into a proper page object... I don't think you'll probably need it.
4. I would also recommend that you create component page objects, e.g. Cards, some of the toolbars. A "page object" doesn't have to be an entire page. It can be any reusable component. You would take some of the functions available in the `Services` class and move them to components like `TimerMenu`, `ProjectBar`, and so on to represent the different toolbars at the top of the page and their functions.
5. You would have a `CardsPage` page object that represents the cards page, e.g. https://tmpapp.theamalgama.com/#/projects/681/cards, but you would also have a `CardComponent` that represents an actual card on the page, the stuff contained within a `<card>` tag. The `CardComponent` would contain the functionality for a single card... the name, the play button for that card, the done icon for that card, the delete/edit/etc options for that card, and so on.

Now to the actual answer. I wrote a `CardComponent` class, as I suggested you write. You pass in the name of the card and it gets a handle to it. From there, you can just call `card.delete()` or `card.whatever()` and that action will be done on the card you specified. It makes handling individual cards, projects, etc. so much easier. Updates to the functionality of a card is easy... changes go in the `CardComponent` page object, etc.

```
public class CardComponent
{
    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebElement card;
    private By deleteCardLocator = By.xpath(".//p[@class='option-list-option'][.='Delete']");
    private By acceptDeleteButtonLocator = By.xpath("//button[.='Accept']");

    public CardComponent(WebDriver webDriver, String cardName)
    {
        driver = webDriver;
        card = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//card[contains(., '" + cardName + "')]")));
    }

    public void delete()
    {
        openMenu();
        card.findElement(deleteCardLocator).click();
        driver.findElement(acceptDeleteButtonLocator).click();
    }

    private void openMenu()
    {
        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(card).perform();
        card.findElement(By.id("dots")).click();
    }
}
```

To use this code, you navigate to the cards page and call

```
CardComponent card = new CardComponent(driver, "card to delete");
card.delete();
```

I created a couple new cards and tested this code and it works.

Comment: JeffC, thanks so much for all your recommendations!! I'll read carefully and improve the code. Thanks for your time. I have one question, can you recommend to me any tutorial, video, etc. to learn how to do handcraft XPaths, please? I've searched in google but i didn't find nothing about how to build non absolute xpaths

Comment: I can't say there's any one in particular that I think is good but most talk about handcrafting XPaths, e.g. https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html. Most of what I learned is from reading SO questions and answers and googling things.